# Not Displaying Data When Setting Value in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanted to display the info of a person when I try to click the `onPrint` button.
Right now, it just doesn't display on the print preview.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-oskar-rf90xx?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

```
  onPrint(list: any) {
    this.selectedInfo = list;
    print();
  }


<div *ngFor="let list of lists; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <td>
    {{ list.name }} -
    <button type="button" (click)="onPrint(list)">Print</button>
  </td>
</div>

<div id="printSection">
  <h1>SAMPLE HEADER TITLE</h1>
  <div>{{ selectedInfo.name }}</div>
  <div>{{ selectedInfo.description }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your Stackblitz example seems to be broken. There are multiple errors.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen. Pls check again. I added codesandbox instead

Comment: The errors were not because you used stackblitz, but because of your sample code.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen. Yes thats my problem. When I try to click "Print". Data doesn't appear on print preview.

Comment: That aside, you have fundamental problems with your code, such as referencing variables that have not even been declared in your controller, among other things. Please review your code and update your question.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen. I have edited my question. but it seems its displaying the previous clicked item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

The OP has changed the question, and removed reactive form from the question (per his comment in my answer). With the latest change, it requires a timeout, since the `print()` function executing, before the UI element is getting rendered. The setTimeout() will add some delay and allow the rendered to add the UI elements.

```
onPrint(list: any) {
    this.selectedInfo = list;
    setTimeout(() => { print() }, 1000);
}
```

Stackblitz: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-https-dch04h

Original:

There's mismatching form name (`displayForm` in component, but `printForm` in html) and some coding issue in your Stackblitz. I have cleaned up most of it.

Also, I think it's better if you split your form to have one to one mapping the form and list fields. Makes it easier to work with each of them.

Full change available here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-bassi-e6042s

app.component.ts:

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.displayForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ["", Validators.required],
      desc: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onPrint(list: { name: string; description: string }) {
    console.log(list);
    this.displayForm.controls.name.setValue(list.name);
    this.displayForm.controls.desc.setValue(list.description);
    console.log(this.displayForm.controls.name.value);
    console.log(this.displayForm.controls.desc.value);
    print();
  }
```

app.component.html:

```
<div id="printSection">
  <form [formGroup]="displayForm">
    <h1>SAMPLE HEADER TITLE</h1>
    <div>{{ displayForm?.controls?.name?.value }}</div>
    <div>{{ displayForm?.controls?.desc?.value }}</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited my question and I didn't use reactive forms anymore. Maybe its not needed. Right now the problem is, it seems its displaying the previous clicked item. You have the same problem also on your answer here

Comment: Added "Updated" section with the latest answer. From my testing, I see the latest object being rendered for print(). Hope you see the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the content you are trying to print is not rendered. Before you print the screen you need to wait. Also while assigning object to form control you should create a formgroup first.
I think setTimeout() function will help you..

You can see example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3zaxj4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```js
onPrint(list: {}) {
    this.displayForm.get('info').setValue(list);
     setTimeout(() => {
            print();
    }, 50);
  }
```

Comment: I don't know how timeout of 0ms also working..